# Binary Search Tree class - identifier "ItemType" is undefined

Tags: c++, templates

I copied this code from my data structures textbook:

```
#pragma once // remove intellisense error

//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

// Listing 16-4.

/** Link-based implementation of the ADT binary search tree.
 @file BinarySearchTree.h */

#ifndef _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE
#define _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE

#include "BinaryTreeInterface.h"
#include "BinaryNode.h"
#include "BinaryNodeTree.h"
#include "NotFoundException.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

template<class ItemType>
class BinarySearchTree : public BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>
{
private:
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;

protected:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Protected Utility Methods Section:
   // Recursive helper methods for the public methods.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Recursively finds where the given node should be placed and
   // inserts it in a leaf at that point.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* insertInorder(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                       BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNode);

   // Removes the given target value from the tree while maintaining a
   // binary search tree.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                     const ItemType target,
                                     bool& success);

   // Removes a given node from a tree while maintaining a
   // binary search tree.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr);

   // Removes the leftmost node in the left subtree of the node
   // pointed to by nodePtr.
   // Sets inorderSuccessor to the value in this node.
   // Returns a pointer to the revised subtree.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeLeftmostNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                            ItemType& inorderSuccessor);

   // Returns a pointer to the node containing the given value,
   // or nullptr if not found.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr,
                                  const ItemType& target) const;

public:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Constructor and Destructor Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinarySearchTree();
   BinarySearchTree(const ItemType& rootItem);
   BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& tree);
   virtual ~BinarySearchTree();

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Methods Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   bool isEmpty() const;
   int getHeight() const;
   int getNumberOfNodes() const;
   ItemType getRootData() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
   void setRootData(const ItemType& newData) const
   throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
   bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
   void clear();
   ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const
   throw(NotFoundException);
   bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Traversals Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
   void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
   void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Overloaded Operator Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& operator=(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& rightHandSide);   
}; // end BinarySearchTree



#endif
```

I'm getting this error: `identifier "ItemType" is undefined` for all uses of `ItemType` including and beyond its first use in the protected section of the class. There's no error in this line of the private section:

```
BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;
```

Also, it doesn't like when `const` is used on a member function, giving the error "a type qualifier is not allowed on a non-member function. What is the problem here?

Headers:

```
#pragma once // removes intellisense error

//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

/** Listing 15-1.
 @file BinaryTreeInterface.h */

#ifndef _BINARY_TREE_INTERFACE
#define _BINARY_TREE_INTERFACE

template<class ItemType>
class BinaryTreeInterface
{
public:
   /** Tests whether this binary tree is empty.
    @return True if the binary tree is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Gets the height of this binary tree.
    @return The height of the binary tree. */
   virtual int getHeight() const = 0;

   /** Gets the number of nodes in this binary tree.
    @return The number of nodes in the binary tree. */
   virtual int getNumberOfNodes() const = 0;

   /** Gets the data that is in the root of this binary tree.
    @pre  The binary tree is not empty.
    @post  The root’s data has been returned, and the binary tree is unchanged.
    @return  The data in the root of the binary tree. */
   virtual ItemType getRootData() const = 0;

   /** Replaces the data item in the root of this binary tree
       with the given data, if the tree is not empty. However, if
       the tree is empty, inserts a new root node containing the
       given data into the tree.
    @pre  None.
    @post  The data in the root of the binary tree is as given.
    @param newData  The data for the root. */
   virtual void setRootData(const ItemType& newData) = 0;

   /** Adds a new node containing the given data to this binary tree.
    @param newData  The data for the new node.
    @post  The binary tree contains a new node.
    @return  True if the addition is successful, or false not. */
   virtual bool add(const ItemType& newData) = 0;

   /** Removes the node containing the given data item from this binary tree.
    @param data  The data value to remove from the binary tree.
    @return  True if the removal is successful, or false not. */
   virtual bool remove(const ItemType& data) = 0;

   /** Removes all nodes from this binary tree. */
   virtual void clear() = 0;

   /** Gets a specific entry in this binary tree.
    @post  The desired entry has been returned, and the binary tree
       is unchanged. If no such entry was found, an exception is thrown.
    @param anEntry  The entry to locate.
    @return  The entry in the binary tree that matches the given entry.
    @throw  NotFoundException if the given entry is not in the tree. */
   virtual ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const
                    throw(NotFoundException) = 0;

   /** Tests whether a given entry occurs in this binary tree.
    @post  The binary search tree is unchanged.
    @param anEntry  The entry to find.
    @return  True if the entry occurs in the tree, or false if not. */
   virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

   /** Traverses this binary tree in preorder (inorder, postorder) and
       calls the function visit once for each node.
    @param visit A client-defined function that performs an operation on
       or with the data in each visited node. */
   virtual void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const = 0;
   virtual void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const = 0;
   virtual void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const = 0;
}; // end BinaryTreeInterface
#endif
```

-

```
#pragma once // removes intellisense error

//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

/** A class of nodes for a link-based binary tree.
 Listing 16-2.
 @file BinaryNode.h */

#ifndef _BINARY_NODE
#define _BINARY_NODE

template<class ItemType>
class BinaryNode
{   
private:
   ItemType              item;           // Data portion
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftChildPtr;   // Pointer to left child
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightChildPtr;  // Pointer to right child

public:
   BinaryNode();
   BinaryNode(const ItemType& anItem);
   BinaryNode(const ItemType& anItem,
              BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr,
              BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr);

   void setItem(const ItemType& anItem);
   ItemType getItem() const;

   bool isLeaf() const;

   BinaryNode<ItemType>* getLeftChildPtr() const;
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* getRightChildPtr() const;

   void setLeftChildPtr(BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr);
   void setRightChildPtr(BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr);            
}; // end BinaryNode


#endif
```

-

```
#pragma once // removes intellisense error

//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

/** ADT binary tree: Link-based implementation.
 Listing 16-3.
 @file BinaryNodeTree.h */

#ifndef _BINARY_NODE_TREE
#define _BINARY_NODE_TREE

#include <iostream>

#include "BinaryTreeInterface.h"
#include "BinaryNode.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
#include "NotFoundException.h"


template<class ItemType>
class BinaryNodeTree : public BinaryTreeInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;

protected:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Protected Utility Methods Section:
   // Recursive helper methods for the public methods.
   //------------------------------------------------------------

   int getHeightHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const;
   int getNumberOfNodesHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const;

   // Recursively deletes all nodes from the tree.
   void destroyTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr);

   // Recursively adds a new node to the tree in a left/right fashion to
   // keep the tree balanced.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* balancedAdd(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                     BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr);

   // Removes the target value from the tree by calling moveValuesUpTree
   // to overwrite value with value from child.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                     const ItemType target, bool& success);

   // Copies values up the tree to overwrite value in current node until
   // a leaf is reached; the leaf is then removed, since its value is
   // stored in the parent.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* moveValuesUpTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr);

   // Recursively searches for target value in the tree by using a
   // preorder traversal.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr,
                                  const ItemType& target,
                                  bool& success) const;

   // Copies the tree rooted at treePtr and returns a pointer to
   // the copy.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* copyTree(const BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;

   // Recursive traversal helper methods:
   void preorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;
   void inorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;
   void postorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;

public:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Constructor and Destructor Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinaryNodeTree();
   BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem);
   BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem,
                  const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>* leftTreePtr,
                  const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>* rightTreePtr);
   BinaryNodeTree(const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>& tree);
   virtual ~BinaryNodeTree();

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public BinaryTreeInterface Methods Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   bool isEmpty() const;
   int getHeight() const;
   int getNumberOfNodes() const;
   ItemType getRootData() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
   void setRootData(const ItemType& newData);
   bool add(const ItemType& newData); // Adds a node
   bool remove(const ItemType& data); // Removes a node
   void clear();
   ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const throw(NotFoundException);
   bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Traversals Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
   void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
   void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Overloaded Operator Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinaryNodeTree& operator=(const BinaryNodeTree& rightHandSide);
}; // end BinaryNodeTree


//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

// PARITALLY COMPLETE.

/** @file BinaryTree.cpp */


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Protected Utility Methods Section
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class ItemType>
int BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getHeightHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const
{
   if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
      return 0;
   else
      return 1 + max(getHeightHelper(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()), 
                     getHeightHelper(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()));
}  // end getHeightHelper

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::balancedAdd(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                                            BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr)
{
   if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
      return newNodePtr;
   else
   {
      BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr = subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr();
      BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr = subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr();

      if (getHeightHelper(leftPtr) > getHeightHelper(rightPtr))
      {
         rightPtr = balancedAdd(rightPtr , newNodePtr);
         subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(rightPtr );
      }
      else
      {
         leftPtr = balancedAdd(leftPtr, newNodePtr);
         subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(leftPtr);
      }  // end if

      return subTreePtr;
   }  // end if
}  // end balancedAdd

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::copyTree(const BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const
{
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* newTreePtr = nullptr;

   // Copy tree nodes during a preorder traversal
   if (treePtr != nullptr)
   {
      // Copy node
       newTreePtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(treePtr->getItem(), nullptr, nullptr);
       newTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(copyTree(treePtr->getLeftChildPtr()));
      newTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(copyTree(treePtr->getRightChildPtr()));
   }  // end if

   return newTreePtr;
}  // end copyTree

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::destroyTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr)
{
   if (subTreePtr != nullptr)
   {
      destroyTree(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
      destroyTree(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
      delete subTreePtr;
   }  // end if
}  // end destroyTree

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Protected Tree Traversal Sub-Section
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::inorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const
{
   if (treePtr != nullptr)
   {
      inorder(visit, treePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
      ItemType theItem = treePtr->getItem();
      visit(theItem);
      inorder(visit, treePtr->getRightChildPtr());
   }  // end if
}  // end inorder

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      PUBLIC METHODS BEGIN HERE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Constructor and Destructor Section
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree() : rootPtr(nullptr)
{
}  // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem)
{
   rootPtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(rootItem, nullptr, nullptr);
}  // end constructor

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem,
                                         const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>* leftTreePtr,
                                         const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>* rightTreePtr)
{
    rootPtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(rootItem, copyTree(leftTreePtr->rootPtr), 
                                                 copyTree(rightTreePtr->rootPtr));
}  // end constructor

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree(const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>& treePtr)
{
   rootPtr = copyTree(treePtr.rootPtr);
}  // end copy constructor

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::~BinaryNodeTree()
{
   destroyTree(rootPtr);
}  // end destructor

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Public BinaryTreeInterface Methods Section
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class ItemType>
bool BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newData)
{
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(newData);
   rootPtr = balancedAdd(rootPtr, newNodePtr);
   return true;
}  // end add

}  // end contains

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Public Traversals Section
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
   inorder(visit, rootPtr);
}  // end inorderTraverse


#endif
```

Comment: I'm not getting those errors when I compile it... Perhaps show us a bit of your headers?

Comment: @Xymostech Added the main headers.

Comment: It looks like you have an extraneous `}` near the end of `BinaryNodeTree.h`. That's the only serious problem I can see. Does that fix it?

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Looks like I've got some more issues now; maybe you could help me with them? 

'binarytreeinterface.h(64): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NotFoundException''


I have no idea where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an extraneous `}` near the end of `BinaryTreeNode.h`.

Also, I'd recommend just getting rid of all the exception specifications (all the things that look like `throw(type)` at the end of functions). They were deprecated in C++11 because they weren't useful.

Comment: Why were the exception specifications not allowing my code to compile?

Comment: @JamesGold Were you compiling in C++11 mode?

Comment: How can I check that? I'm running Visual C++ 2010 express.

Comment: @JamesGold Maybe your compiler doesn't like exception specifications? You could try making a smaller test case and see if it chokes on something like that. But I really don't know.